# Relaciones en mongoose con id personalizado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

tengo 2 modelos que quiero relacionar para poder realizar consultas en mongoose.

**Modelo Usuarios**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let csvuaSchema = new Schema({
 codigo: { type: 'String' },
 georeferencia: { type: 'String'},
 tipo: { type: 'String' }
})

let csvua = mongoose.model('csvua', csvuaSchema)

export default csvua
```

**Modelo Lecturas**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let csvlecSchema = new Schema({
 codigo: { type: 'String', ref: 'csvuas'},
 fecha_lectura: { type: 'Date' },
 lectura: { type: 'Number' }
})

let csvlec = mongoose.model('csvlec', csvlecSchema)

export default csvlec
```

La información la obtengo de archivos csv y la subo a mongodb de forma masiva y necesito poder consultar todas las lecturas de un usuario a través del código de usuario. ¿Puedo usar el código de usuario para hacer una consulta que obtenga todas las lecturas del usuario o es necesario usar el _id del usuario?. No quiero usar el _id que genera mongoose para el usuario por que al tratar de agregar lecturas de forma masiva tendría que consultar el _id del usuario con su código y creo que no es lo ideal para el rendimiento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el ObjectId cuando insertas el documento de nuevo, por ejemplo, `user.insert({_id:"pepe",apellido:"Lopez"})`, de esta forma insertaría el ObjectId que tu necesites pero ten en cuenta de que tendría que ser único.

Ahora, según mi experiencia lo mejor que me ha ido a sido usar el ObjectId que crea MongoDB al insertar el documento ya que él se encarga de que sea único y, ademas, las búsquedas que tienes relacionadas por su propio ObjectId son mas efectivas y rápidas.

Si tu problema es la relación de colecciones, puedes hacer utilizar el proceso 'aggregate()' con la etapa '$lookup' de MongoDB si tienes disponible desde la version 3.2 o superior de MongoDB, donde puedes relacionar colecciones del campo que necesites y devolver el dato ya relacionado. Te pongo un ejemplo para que puedas hacerte una idea:

```
csvuaSchema.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { //Etapa para buscar (símil al find)
            codigo: '1234' //Campo de búsqueda
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: { 
            from: 'csvlec', //Nombre de la colecccion a relacionar
            localField: 'codigo', //Nombre del campo de la coleccion actual
            foreignField: 'codigo', //Nombre del campo de la coleccion a relacionar
            as: 'lecturas' //Nombre del campo donde se insertara todos los documentos relacionados
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            codigo: 1,
            georeferencia: 1,
            lecturas: 1 //Devolverà un Array de documentos que tiene el usuario '1234'
        }
    }
])
```

Salida:

```
    [{
        _id: ObjectId("5bf6f3d25f2ea179733c1315")
        codigo: '1234',
        georeferencia: 'tugeoreferencia',
        tipo: 'tutipo',
        lecturas: [
            {
                codigo: '1234',
                fecha_lectura: 'fecha1',
                lectura: 'lectura1'
            },
            {
                codigo: '1234',
                fecha_lectura: 'fecha2',
                lectura: 'fecha2'
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Más info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html

Sobre el rendimiento de las búsquedas, te recomiendo que incluyas indice en las colecciones que te ayudara mucho en las búsquedas y mas si tienes que extraer muchos documentos. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

No puedo probarlo ahora mismo, pero en teoría si que podrías hacerlo, eso sí deberías asegurarte de que los identificadores fueran únicos(usa index y unique en el usuario)